# Playing sound with non-constant sample rate

Tags: sound

EDIT: [Posting to Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/794957) too.

I have a dataset of the form

```
{{a1,t1},{a2,t2},...,{an,tn}}
```

where `ai` is the level and `ti` is the time of that level. Is it possible to play this as a sound in Mathematica?

Example data (written in a different form for clarity):

```
ai:   0.0006    0.0407    0.0808    0.1210    0.1611    0.2013    0.2415    0.2816
ti:   0.0001    0.0074    0.0147    0.0220    0.0293    0.0366    0.0439    0.0512
```

Comment: I don't believe *Mathematica* can handle nonequispaced samples as audio natively. You could use `Interpolation[]` to resample, but it is admittedly cheating. Is there really no way for you to obtain equispaced samples?

Comment: @J.M. But the data given by the OP *is* equispaced... Daniel, what should happen in between those times? Should the intensity smoothly ramp up and down, or should it be held constant at the value shown for the duration of the interval? What is the unit of $ti$?

Comment: @J.M. I see. Well, perhaps the OP will shed further light on this.

Comment: @Marco, in that case, it can be converted to a `TimeSeries[]` object that can be handled by `ListPlay[]`.

Comment: @J.M. The data is not necessarily equispaced, it was just in this example. Between these times should remain constant (I think, I might change this). The point of this is that the `ti` are not necessarily equispaced.

Comment: @MarcoB The unit here is seconds, and the `ti` should have the ability to not be equispaced.

Comment: "Between these times should remain constant" - with that assumption, you can indeed resample your data using `Interpolation[]`; setting `InterpolationOrder -> 0` will impose your condition.